# Control does not pass to action - fibonacci series in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

The control does not pass to action when the form is submitted. 
I have a breakpoint in the action but control does not go there. thanks. Control does not pass to action - fibonacci in mvc4

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult finonacci()
    {
        return View();
    }




    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }

     @using (Html.BeginForm("finonacci","Home",FormMethod.Post))
     {
      <p>Enter a number</p> @Html.TextBox("Input")
        <br />
        <input type="button" id="btnsubmit" value="Check" />

     }
```

Comment: Don't you want "Fibonacci"?

Comment: Did you try that it goes to another action of same controller ?

Comment: yes but first i wanted to get the control then implement the logic.

Comment: I think you have to change type="button" to type="submit"

Comment: yes control goes to index action.

Comment: that worked...thanks dotnetstep and everyone..

Answer (score 0):

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("fibonacci", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <p>Enter a number</p> @Html.TextBox("Input")
    <br />
    <input type="Submit" id="btnsubmit" value="Check" />
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult fibonacci(int Input)
{
    if (Input > 1)
    {
       int a = 0;
       int b = 1;
       // In N steps compute Fibonacci sequence iteratively.
       for (int i = 0; i < Input; i++)
       {
           int temp = a;
           a = b;
           b = temp + b;
           Response.Write("<p>fibonacci series " + b.ToString() + "</p>");
       }        
      return View("Index");
    }
    return View("Index");
}



}
```

Comment: Your code is faulty. If you write the response and the Redirect to an Action method, will the user ever see the result?

Comment: i made the changes, i am new to mvc4. As of now i get the result rendered as a paragraph. thanks for noticing.